# Is it possible to generate an app icon with a transparent background for Android 12 and above?

Tags: android, react-native

I tried to use some 3rd party tools to generate an app icon with transparent background and Android Studio's Image Asset tool(Hedgehog) by following [Google's guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/create-app-icons#access) with no success.
It doesn't give the option to choose opacity:

[image]

I tried to use a transparent .png picture as a 'Background Layer' with no luck, the app icon was filled with white color.

Most of the questions in regards to a transparent app icon are pretty old and do not apply anymore.

From my understanding there is no way to create an app icon with this specification and I just wanted to confirm this in case I missed anything.